# sql permission issue when creating a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've made a c# program to create a database in the localhost ms sql as below:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "SERVER = " + serverName + "; DATABASE = master; Integrated Security=SSPI";

    string query = " CREATE DATABASE " + dbName + " ON PRIMARY "
                        + " (NAME = " + dataFileName + ", "
                        + " FILENAME = '" + schemaPath + "', "
                        + " SIZE = 2MB,"
                        + " FILEGROWTH = 10%) "
                        + " LOG ON (NAME =" + logFileName + ", "
                        + " FILENAME = '" + logFilePath + "', "
                        + " SIZE = 1MB, "
                        + " FILEGROWTH = 10%) ";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Database has been created successfully!");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to create the db. " + ex.ToString());
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

It works perfectly fine on my pc, but fails on another machine:
I do have the write permissions to the folders which I've specified.

> Failed to create the db. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Directory lookup for the file
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2.mdf" failed with the operating
>   system error 5(Access is denied.). CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file
>   names listed could not be created. Check related errors.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, Tds ParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName,Boolean async)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   com.appneta.test.DB_DataLoader.createDB(String dbName)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any progress on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "I do have the write permissions to the folders which I've specified." - it feels like you are talking about you the user.

You need to make sure that the service account SQL Server is running under has write permissions on the folder path you are trying to write to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running visual studio as Administrator?